# Is Grants Management extension/component included in Spark?

Tags: civicrm-spark, civigrant

I'm working with a small local racial justice group looking for their first CRM. Because they need a mix of advocacy, comms, & regular fundraising tools, CiviCRM came up in my searches and Spark seems like the easiest way for a small org to get started.

One thing that isn't clear from the Spark landing page is whether Spark includes the Grants component/extension (CiviGrant)? Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest emailing spark@civicrm.org to get a definitive answer, the 'Essentials' package does have limited extensions and the team supporting/running Spark can confirm if CiviGrant is one of them or if not on that package if it is part of 'Pro'.